# What book(s) reference dates A.S. (After Shannon) and what is the in-universe explanation for its origin?

Tags: story-identification, authors

After `01:20:30` in the delightful video [The Bit Player | Claude Shannon | Father of Information Theory | IEEE Information Theory Society](https://youtu.be/JP1Ljp8X6hg?t=4830) Shannon's last graduate student and Thinking Machine's [Danny Hillis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_Hillis) says:

> **There's Science Fiction books in which the dates of things are so many years A.S. where the A.S. stands for "After Shannon".** In some sense, if you look at human civilization, the sudden change in human civilization that was created by the digital revolution, computers... happened at such a short period of time that there's nothing else like that in history.
>
> So it could very well be that historically  people will look back and say "what happened there?" And if you were going to tie it to anybody, Shannon is the one that gave us the tools that people would still be using in the future.
>
> So it's not so implausible that people would start measuring years after Shannon.

**Question:** Which book(s) and author(s) reference dates A.S. (After Shannon) and what is the in-universe explanation for its origin?

---

Related:

- Wikipedia [Claude Shannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Shannon)
- HSM SE: [What contributions from Glavieux & Thitimajshima were "merged" into Claude Berrou's now-famous 1993 talk "Near Shannon limit error-correcting coding"?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/14432/3869)

Comment: Apparently asked about here an Reddit also:  https://www.reddit.com/r/3Blue1Brown/comments/k5iu4x/does_anyone_know_the_science_fiction_novel_grant/

Comment: @Buzz bingo! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Agbh95KyWxY

Comment: I'm always a little suspicious of statements that say something like *There is a book that ...* but don't name the book. Such statements seem to me like the SF equivalent of an "urban legend". My collection is a tiny fraction of all SF books published, but I'm pretty certain that none of my collection use the concept of a era dated *After Shannon*. Such a book may well exist but the concept is not mainstream in SF.

Comment: @JohnRennie curiouser and curiouser!  Danny Hillis and [Grant Sanderson](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/262876/what-books-reference-dates-a-s-after-shannon-and-what-is-the-in-universe-ex?noredirect=1#comment724562_262876) don't seem to be ardent urban legend mongers to me, but it would be funny to find out that in the end there are no such books!

Comment: "Brave New World" famously had "the year of Our Ford". I don't recall a story doing something similar for Shannon though

Comment: @JohnRennie: There is an elegant reference, that is too large to be contained within the margins... :-D

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Great! Now we have to spend nearly 400 years looking for the answer to this question...

Comment: @JohnRennie ...and/or it may not be in English, e.g. [克劳德·香农](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%8B%E5%8A%B3%E5%BE%B7%C2%B7%E9%A6%99%E5%86%9C)